# Como agrupar COUNTs para diferentes consultas em uma só?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select

Preciso fazer um consulta SQL para contar indicações, eu tenho as seguintes *querys*:

```
SELECT 'FACEBOOK', COUNT(id) FROM `clientes` where indicacao like '%face%' 

SELECT 'Instagram', COUNT(id) FROM `clientes` where indicacao like '%insta%'

SELECT 'google', COUNT(id) FROM `clientes` where indicacao like '%google%'

SELECT 'panfleto', COUNT(id) FROM `clientes` where indicacao like '%panf%' 

SELECT 'indicacao', COUNT(id) FROM `clientes` where indicacao like '%ind%' 

SELECT 'radio', COUNT(id) FROM `clientes` where indicacao like '%radio%' 

SELECT 'outros',  COUNT(id) as total FROM `clientes` where indicacao not like '%radio%' and indicacao not like '%face%' and indicacao not LIKE '%insta%' and indicacao not like '%google%' and indicacao not like '%panf%' and indicacao not like '%ind%' and indicacao not like '%radio%'
```

A minha duvida é: Eu consigo fazer essa mesma pesquisa sem precisar fazer todas estas *querys*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim você consegue unificá-las em uma única query, para isso você fará uso de [CASE WHEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) e [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html).

**GROUP BY:**

Com seu uso é possível agruparmos diversos registros com base em uma ou mais colunas de uma tabela.

**CASE WHEN:**

A expressão CASE é usada para avaliar várias condições e retornar um valor único para cada condição.

**Veja o exemplo abaixo:**

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN Indicacao NOT LIKE '%face%' 
        AND Indicacao NOT LIKE '%insta%'  
        AND Indicacao NOT LIKE '%google%' 
        AND Indicacao NOT LIKE '%panf%' 
        AND Indicacao NOT LIKE '%ind%'
        AND Indicacao NOT LIKE '%radio%' THEN 
    'Outros'
   ELSE
     Indicacao
   END AS 'Indicacao'
   , COUNT(ID) 
FROM clientes
GROUP BY 
  CASE WHEN Indicacao NOT LIKE '%face%' 
        AND Indicacao NOT LIKE '%insta%'  
        AND Indicacao NOT LIKE '%google%' 
        AND Indicacao NOT LIKE '%panf%' 
        AND Indicacao NOT LIKE '%ind%'
        AND Indicacao NOT LIKE '%radio%' THEN 
    'Outros'
   ELSE
     Indicacao
   END
ORDER BY ID;
```

[SQLFiddle - Exemplo funcionando online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16934/16)

Comment: Eu coloquei agora com utilizando `LIKE`, mas você poderia remover espaços também caso tive-se certeza que não tenha outros caracteres indesejados.

Comment: Beleza, excelente resposta. +1 (Y)

Comment: Boa! valeuu!!!!